# How to align a responsive image in a leaflet map with css

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, maps

I'm doing a webmap (with leaflet). This map contains one png image and i want to display in mobile phone with max-width:50% style. 
The image shows up with max-width:50% but i can't align the image at right of the map.

This is my js code to add the image:

```
var logo1 = L.control();
logo1.onAdd = function(map){
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div');
    div.innerHTML= "<div href='https://www.uma.es/'><img class='resp1' src='logo1.png'/></div>";

    return div;
}  logo1.addTo(map);
```

and this is my css style:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
img.resp1 {
    max-width: 50%;
    text-align: right;
} } @media screen and (min-width: 760px) { img.resp1 {
max-width: 100%;}}
```

the result and graphic explanation of the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always vertical or horizontal center any element if the container has a fixed height using a relative position for the parent element and a absolute position for the child element like so for center x and y:

```css
.container-elment {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-elment">
  <div class="child-element">

  </div>
</div>
```

for center x:

```css
.container-elment {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-elment">
  <div class="child-element">

  </div>
</div>
```

for center y :

```css
.container-elment {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}

.child-element {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-elment">
  <div class="child-element">

  </div>
</div>
```